# power series of $\frac1{3+x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have started studying representations of functions as power series and have encountered a small confusion: Given the function $\frac{1}{3+x^2}$, is it valid to represent it as the power series $\sum (-2-x^2)^n$ ? $\left(\frac1{3+x^2} = \frac1{1-(-2-x^2)}\right)$

Comment: What you wrote is not a power series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could, but remember that a power series expansion depends on the point that you're expanding around. For example, the power series expansion of $1/(1-x)$ is usually taken around $x=0$. So if you represent $1/(3 + x^2)$ as $1/(1 - (-2 - x^2))$ and use the expansion around $(-2 - x^2) = 0$, then you'd essentially be expanding around $x = \pm \sqrt{-2}$, which may not make sense over real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways to make the series of $\frac 1{1+u^2}$ appear than to shift the series like this.

For instance $\dfrac 1{3+x^2}=\dfrac {\frac 13}{1+\frac {x^2}3}=\dfrac{\frac 13}{1+u^2}\ $ with $u=\frac x{\sqrt{3}}$

Another possibility is to find directly the power series with

$(3+x^2)\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=3a_0+3a_1x+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty (3a_n+a_{n-2})x^n=1\implies \begin{cases}3a_0=1\\a_1=0\\3a_n+a_{n-2}=0\end{cases}$